# Binding Mode OneTime in MvxRecyclerView

Tags: mvvmcross

Is it possible to set the binding for one of my properties to be `OneTime` when the layout is used in a `MvxRecyclerView`? I set it to `OneTime`, but it keeps rebinding as I scroll through the list. This is the `TextView` that it keeps rebinding to:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_huge"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    local:MvxBind="Text IsAddedToCart, Converter=BoolToFontAwesome, ConverterParameter=fa-shopping-cart|fa-cart-plus; Style ., Converter=String, ConverterParameter=fonts/fontawesome.ttf, Mode=OneTime" />
```

I set the binding mode to `OneTime` for the Style, but it keeps rebinding as I scroll through the items in the list (I know because I put a break point). This is the class for my `Style` binding:

```
public class StyleTextViewBinding : MvxAndroidTargetBinding
{
    readonly TextView _textView;

    public StyleTextViewBinding(TextView textView) : base(textView)
    {
        _textView = textView;
    }

    #region implemented abstract members of MvxConvertingTargetBinding
    protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
    {
        var font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(_textView.Context.Assets, value.ToString());
        _textView.Typeface = font;
        // I put a break point here, and I can see that it keeps rebinding
    }
    #endregion

    public override Type TargetType
    {
        get { return typeof(string); }
    }

    public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode
    {
        get { return MvxBindingMode.OneTime; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OneTime` bindings will only work as such if you do not recycle your Views. Meaning if you don't scroll and change what is bound to the `Style` property from the ViewModel. Then it will only fire once.

Since `RecyclerView` uses the `ViewHolder` pattern, the views themselves are not recreated every time. This means, in order to have the correct state in the shown items, we need to re-bind them every time they reappear on the screen.